# Is it possible to count non-null columns within each row?

Tags: mysql, count

Suppose this data:

```
id      firstname     surname     val1      val2      val3
1       joe           blogs       1         (null)    (null)
2       jane          doe         (null)    2         5
3       bobby         tables      (null)    (null)    (null)
```

I'd like a query that would return:

```
id     count_non_null_vals
1      1
2      2
3      0
```

`COUNT` and `SUM` obviously doesn't work (if they do, educate me!), and whilst we have `GREATEST` and `LEAST` as in-row similies to `MAX`/`MIN`, I can't find something analagous to `COUNT`.

I can make a horrible behemoth of nested `IF`s etc, but in my real-world legacy example there's 30 of these columns, so I'd rather be able to do `COL_COUNT(val1, val2, val3...` etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right from the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)

> COUNT(expr) [over_clause]
>
> **Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows**
> **retrieved by a SELECT statement**. The result is a BIGINT value.
>
> If there are no matching rows, COUNT() returns 0.

Just use [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) function on each column and add them up last

```
SELECT
   id,COUNT(val1)+COUNT(val2)+COUNT(val3) count_non_null_vals
FROM mytable;
```

You can use your PHP / Python / Java to craft the SQL since you have 30 columns.

### UPDATE 2021-09-20 11:45 EDT

I decided to actually write this out for real. Here is what I did:

### MY PROPOSED QUERY

```
SET session sql_mode = '';
SELECT IFNULL(id,'') all_ids
,COUNT(val1)+COUNT(val2)+COUNT(val3) count_non_null_vals
FROM mytable GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;
```

### YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS codemonkey;
CREATE DATABASE codemonkey;
USE codemonkey
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(20),
    surname VARCHAR(20),
    val1 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    val2 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    val3 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO mytable (firstname,surname,val1,val2,val3) VALUES
('joe','blogs',1,NULL,NULL),
('jane','doe',NULL,2,5),
('bobby','tables',NULL,NULL,NULL);
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

### YOUR SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS codemonkey;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE codemonkey;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE codemonkey
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     firstname VARCHAR(20),
    ->     surname VARCHAR(20),
    ->     val1 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     val2 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     val3 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable (firstname,surname,val1,val2,val3) VALUES
    -> ('joe','blogs',1,NULL,NULL),
    -> ('jane','doe',NULL,2,5),
    -> ('bobby','tables',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

### YOUR TABLE

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----+-----------+---------+------+------+------+
| id | firstname | surname | val1 | val2 | val3 |
+----+-----------+---------+------+------+------+
|  1 | joe       | blogs   |    1 | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | jane      | doe     | NULL |    2 |    5 |
|  3 | bobby     | tables  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+-----------+---------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### MY PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET session sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IFNULL(id,'') all_ids
    -> ,COUNT(val1)+COUNT(val2)+COUNT(val3) count_non_null_vals
    -> FROM mytable GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;
+---------+---------------------+
| all_ids | count_non_null_vals |
+---------+---------------------+
| 1       |                   1 |
| 2       |                   2 |
| 3       |                   0 |
|         |                   3 |
+---------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

### BIG CAVEAT

I had to set the session's sql_mode to blank because MySQL does not like doing aggregate queries of this nature. It complains of an invalidate GROUP BY otherwise.

### UPDATE 2021-09-20 12:03 EDT

For those running 5.7/8.0, you can disable sql_mode in the session, run the query and reset it back ....

```
SET @old_sql_mode = @@session.sql_mode;
SET session sql_mode = '';
SELECT IFNULL(id,'') all_ids
,COUNT(val1)+COUNT(val2)+COUNT(val3) count_non_null_vals
FROM mytable GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;
SET session sql_mode = @old_sql_mode;
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, simply summing multiple `COUNT`s didn't occur to me

Comment: I updated my answer with an actual solution

Comment: That IS a big caveat, isn't it.  With my SQL mode of `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` I assume I'll be out of luck?

Comment: You can set it within the DB Connection before calling the query.

Comment: Let me add to this answer ...

Comment: FWIW I've just tried it without changing my sql_mode and it worked fine.  Although I targeted the question at mysql I'm actually using the current version of MariaDB, so maybe this is a change they have.

Comment: In that case, you don't need to touch sql_mode. You might need to do this with mode recent versions of MySQL. Perhaps your version of MariaDB has a blank sq;l_mode. Anyway, I hope this helped you today. (NOTE: I was doing this in MySQL 5.7.34)